# Why do `xwininfo` and `xdotool` give me different window ids?

Tags: x11, terminal-emulator, xdotool

In a tab of a terminal emulator (lxterminal), I try to find out its window id by clicking in the tab and the process which "owns" the window (I am still not sure what is the word to describe the relation between a window and a process, so I use "own"), both by `xwininfo`

```
$ xwininfo -int | grep -Po '(?<=Window id: )[0-9a-zA-Z]+'
31457283
$ xdotool getwindowpid 31457283
1480    
$ ps aux | grep -i 1480
t         1480  0.1  0.3 473204 31240 ?        Sl   Nov21  23:18 lxterminal
```

and `xdotool`

```
$ xdotool selectwindow 
35652689
$ xdotool selectwindow getwindowpid
window 35652689 has no pid associated with it.
```

Why do `xwininfo` and `xdotool` give me different window ids, and thus different process results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a launching script for a VNC client at work (sorry, cannot disclose details) that uses xdotool, the two relevant lines being -

```
w=`xdotool search --name "$VNC_client"`; x=`printf 0x%x $w`; qtembed $x
```

So I suspect from the format conversion specifier (in the printf) that there's a good chance that the different numbers are due to the simple difference in radix used to report their results.